# Raphael Paper Order

Tags: raphael

I have to stick one Raphael paper over a few others, and I need to to make sure that the paper stays on top of the others. I know that for elements I could just do Element.toFront().

Is there any way to do this with Raphael papers?

(Also, there is only one small element in the top paper.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is another solution but you can put one `paper` by `div`. And after that, you can just play with the `z-index`.

Look at this example : http://jsfiddle.net/gLeAZ/